# Find the version of an installed npm package

Tags: node.js, package, npm

How can I find the version of an installed Node.js or npm **package**?

This prints the version of npm itself:

```
npm -v <package-name>
```

This prints a cryptic error:

```
npm version <package-name>
```

This prints the package version *on the registry* (i.e., the latest version available):

```
npm view <package-name> version
```

How do I get the **installed version**?

Comment: On my installation, "npm -v <package-name>" reports the version of npm, itself. To list the latest version of a package in the registry, I have found that "npm view <package-name> version" gets the job done.

Comment: `npm show` shows the latest in npm, not installed

Comment: most of the time <module-name> -v should work. However, this depends on whether or not the package developer(s) added cli functionality to their packages.

Comment: If you're in the directory that its package.json is in, you can use `npm pkg get version`.

Answer (score 3403):

Use `npm list` for local packages or `npm list -g` for globally installed packages.

You can find the version of a specific package by passing its name as an argument. For example, `npm list grunt` will result in:

```
projectName@projectVersion /path/to/project/folder
└── grunt@0.4.1
```

Alternatively, you can just run `npm list` without passing a package name as an argument to see the versions of all your packages:

```
├─┬ cli-color@0.1.6
│ └── es5-ext@0.7.1
├── coffee-script@1.3.3
├── less@1.3.0
├─┬ sentry@0.1.2
│ ├── file@0.2.1
│ └── underscore@1.3.3
└── uglify-js@1.2.6
```

You can also add `--depth=0` argument to list installed packages without their dependencies.

Comment: On mac and linux it's nice to add " | grep module_name", to filter the desired module version. Especially when running globally with -g. For example: "npm list -g | grep express"   to get the installed express version.

Comment: If you want a specific module, you can run it like `npm list less-middleware` as an example.

Comment: Per @guya's tip for *nix based systems, on Windows you can use PowerShell for similar results: `| select-string module_name` to filter the module.  Or, if you're using Git Bash (or just Bash, for that matter), you can use `grep`.

Comment: If you can't remember `list`, `npm ls` also works. In fact, many npm commands have aliases, and moreover, if you type a substring of a command, if this substring is unambiguous, it will work also; for instance `npm ls`, `npm list`, `npm lis` are all the same. If you want more verbose output, try `npm ll` (but probably you want `--depth=0` added to it).

Comment: this always gives "npm ERR! 1" for me, both with and without `-g`

Comment: For Windows you can also use `| findstr "module_name"`´, but using the `npm list [-g] <module_name>` solution given by @juanpaco above works better.

Comment: The output isn't the best for parsing with a script. Is there really not a way to get an output that is just the package version without having to do something like `npm list -g | awk -F@ '/<package>/ { print $2}'`

Comment: Currentliy npm 5.5.1 has a --parseable option. Try `npm ls --depth=0 --parseable`. See [doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls).

Comment: @taz `--parseable` option is not showing the version of the installed package! (npm 6.14)

Comment: @guya Windows also has a way to filter like grep in Linux. e.g.
`npm list | find "module_name"` from the command prompt

Comment: With turbo I had to use --pattern `npm list --pattern grunt`

Answer (score 1037):

Another quick way of finding out what packages are installed **locally** and **without their dependencies** is to use:

```
npm list --depth=0
```

Which gives you something like

```
├── bower@0.8.6
├── grunt@0.4.1
├── grunt-bower-requirejs@0.4.3
├── grunt-contrib-clean@0.4.1
├── grunt-contrib-coffee@0.7.0
├── grunt-contrib-copy@0.4.1
├── grunt-contrib-imagemin@0.1.4
├── grunt-contrib-jshint@0.1.1
├── grunt-contrib-livereload@0.1.2
├── grunt-contrib-requirejs@0.4.1
├── grunt-regarde@0.1.1
└── grunt-svgmin@0.1.0
```

Obviously, the same can be done globally with `npm list -g --depth=0`.

This method is clearer if you have installed a lot of packages.

To find out which packages need to be updated, you can use `npm outdated -g --depth=0`.

Comment: it's give me same as without the --depth

Comment: it seems they've fixed it in npm 1.4.6. See https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/4733

Comment: Works great with `| grep <package_name>`

Comment: @ygaradon Correct, but the `--depth=0` makes it faster, because it does not have to recursively load dependencies

Comment: `npm list -g --depth=0` for list modules installed globally

Answer (score 293):

`npm view <package> version` - returns the latest available version on the package.

`npm list --depth=0` - returns versions of all installed modules without dependencies.

`npm list` - returns versions of all modules and dependencies.

And lastly to get the Node.js version: `node -v`

Comment: npm view <package> version, goes to the npm remote registry, not local filesystem...

Comment: @AlexanderMills True, but having it here avoids another search for that. Btw, `npm v`, `npm info` and `npm show` are all alias of [`npm view`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/view).

Comment: along the same lines, `npm view <package> versions` will return all the versions for the package and not just the latest one.

Comment: @SalvadorDali Why do you steal the name and the face of a dead person? This should not be accepted...

Answer (score 111):

Use

```
npm info YOUR_PACKAGE version
```

E.g.,

```
npm info grunt version

0.4.5
```

Comment: This doesn't show the installed package version, it just shows the latest available version.

Comment: Agree with @tanner-semerad. I checked into [Docs of npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/view) to clearify it.

`npm info` is alias for `npm view` and in [Docs of npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/view) you will find that standing: 

_This command shows data about a package and prints it to the stream referenced by the outfd config, which defaults to stdout. [...]_
_The default version is "latest" if unspecified._

That's way I vote down.

Comment: Shows the latest version available, not latest installed. Downvoted.

Comment: `npm info YOUR_PACKAGE version` The only one that worked :)

Comment: same, 'npm info YOUR_PACKAGE version' The only one that worked

Comment: No, as mentioned this will show the latest version on the registry. This "seems" to work if by chance your local dependency is on the latest version. But if it's not, you will not see the actual installed (older) version with this command.

Answer (score 91):

From the root of the package do:

```
node -p "require('./package.json').version"
```

(So you need to `cd` into the module's home directory if you are not already there. If you have installed the module with `npm install`, then it will be under `node_modules/<module_name>`.)

Comment: Nice! Quite a bit faster than running "npm list" as the other answers suggest (~1s instead of ~20s) -- at least when you have this code snippet ready! (there should really be an npm plugin to do this...)

Comment: or `node -p "require('./package.json').version"`

Comment: I'd like to oppose @geedew 's comment. This answer suggests to be run in the root folder of the installed module. In the package.json of the installed module you will(!) find the actually installed version.

Comment: Nice one-liner: `(cd node_modules/<package name> && node -p "require('./package.json').version")`

Answer (score 81):

I just used

```
npm list | grep <package name>
```

and it worked great.

On Windows, run:

```
npm list | find <package name>
```

In [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell) run:

```
npm list | sls <package name>
```

Comment: `find` version doesn't work for me - even with quoted string, but powershell works well

Comment: **For Windows users:** `npm list -g --depth=0 |find "<package name>"` Note the *double quotes*

Comment: How do you get only the version (without the rest of the stuff), and not just in Bash, but also in Windows PowerShell? You'd think they would have thought of this a long time ago.

Answer (score 35):

WARNING: This answer shows the latest available version of a module in npm, *not* the currently installed version locally.

---

##### It's very simple.. Just type the below line

```
npm view <package-name> version
```

##### Example

```
npm view redux version
```

I have version 7.2.0 of [Redux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redux_(JavaScript_library)).

Comment: BEWARE: This is NOT showing the installed version. It shows the latest available version on npm.

Answer (score 34):

For local packages:

```
npm list --depth=0
```

For *global* packages:

```
npm list -g --depth=0
```

Answer (score 34):

You can see file *package.json* to see installed packages versions.

To get the list on the command line,

```
npm ls
```

It will give you all installed packages in a project with their respective versions.

For a particular package version,

```
npm ls <package-name>
```

For example,

```
npm ls next
```

It will return version

```
-- next@10.1.3
```

Answer (score 29):

Combining some of the above answers and produces a super simple and super quick lookup.

Run from the project root. There isn’t any need to `cd` into any folder, just one line:

`node -p "require('SOMEPACKAGE/package.json').version"`

Comment: This gives me the error "Package subpath './package.json' is not defined by "exports" in /path/to/SOMEPACKAGE/package.json". Did this used to work until a new node version broke it, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 23):

If you agree to install [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/), you can use the JSON output of `npm list`:

```
npm -j ls <package-name> | jq -r .version
```

Or, if you want to be verbose:

```
npm --json list <package-name> | jq --raw-output '.version'
```

For instance:

```
npm -j ls ghost | jq -r .version
```

Output:

```
0.4.2
```

Also, the JSON format is slightly different for global packages, so you'll need to change the query.

For instance:

```
npm -j -g ls | jq -r .dependencies.ghost.version
```

Output:

```
0.4.2
```

Answer (score 21):

You can also check the version with this command:

`npm info <package name> version`

Comment: Again, it shows the latest version available in the package registry not the version of the currently installed package.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy Agree with its show only latest version like npm info httpaction

Answer (score 18):

I've seen some very creative answers, but you can just do this (for global packages add the --global switch):

```
npm ls package
```

Example:

```
npm ls babel-cli
```

Output:

```
`-- babel-cli@6.26.0
```

The npm documentation says that npm -ls

> This command will print to stdout all the versions of packages that
> are installed, as well as their dependencies, in a tree-structure.

[NPM documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls.html)

Comment: *'..as well as their dependencies, in a tree-structure'* - beware of structure hell (:

Answer (score 15):

If you are brave enough (and have Node.js installed), you can always do something like:

```
echo "console.log(require('./package.json').version);" | node
```

This will print the version of the current package.
You can also modify it to go insane, like this:

```
echo "eval('var result='+require('child_process').execSync('npm version',{encoding:'utf8'})); console.log(result.WHATEVER_PACKAGE_NAME);" | node
```

That will print the version of `WHATEVER_PACKAGE_NAME` package, that is seen by `npm version`.

Comment: `node -e "console.log(require('./package.json').version);"`

Answer (score 14):

To list local packages with the version number use:

`npm ls --depth=0`

To list global packages with the version number use:

`npm ls -g --depth=0`

Answer (score 13):

To see all the installed packages locally or globally, use these commands:

1. `npm list` for local packages or `npm list -g` for globally installed packages.
2. `npm list --depth=0`
3. `npm list | sls <package name>`
4. `node -v`

Answer (score 13):

`npm list --depth 0` is the command which shows all libraries with version, but you can use `npm-check`.

npm-check is a good library to manage all those things regarding the version system event. It will show libraries versions, new version updates, and unused versions, and many more.

To install it, just run:

```
npm install -g npm-check
```

And simply run

```
npm-check
```

Check the screenshot. It is showing everything about the package versions, new version updates, and unused versions.

[image]

It works globally too. Give it a try.

Answer (score 12):

I've built a tool that does exactly that - [qnm](https://github.com/ranyitz/qnm).

### qnm - A simple CLI utility for querying the `node_modules` directory.

Install it using:

```
npm i --global qnm
```

And run:

```
qnm [module]
```

For example:

```
qnm lodash
```

Output:

```
lodash
├── 4.17.5
├─┬ cli-table2
│ └── 3.10.1
└─┬ karma
  └── 3.10.1
```

Which means we have `lodash` installed in the root of the *node_modules folder* folder and two other copies in the *node_modules* folder of `cli-table2` and `karma`.

It's really fast and has some nice features, like tab completion and match search.

Answer (score 11):

Try with:

```
npm list --depth 1 --global packagename
```

Answer (score 11):

**npm list package-name** gives the currently installed version

Answer (score 9):

Here's a portable Unix (using `grep` and `sed`) one-liner that returns the version string of a globally-installed npm package (remove the `g` from `-pg` to query local packages instead):

```
npm ll -pg --depth=0 grunt | grep -o "@.*:" | sed 's/.$//; s/^.//'
```

Output:

```
0.4.5
```

- the `npm ll` outputs a parsable string formatted like: `/usr/lib/node_modules/npm:npm@2.14.8:`;
- the `grep` command extracts the value between `@` and `:`, inclusive;
- the `sed` command removes the surrounding characters.

Comment: With newer versions of npm, there is no trailing colon, so the pipeline is just `| grep -o "@.*" | sed 's/^.//'`.

Answer (score 7):

I added this to my [.bashrc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example) file:

```
function npmv {
    case $# in # Number of arguments passed
    0) v="$(npm -v)" ; # Store output from npm -v in variable
        echo "NPM version is: $v"; # Can't use single quotes
                                   # ${v} would also work
    ;;
    1) s="$(npm list --depth=0 $1 | grep $1 | cut -d @ -f 2)";
       echo "$s";
    ;;
    2) case "$2" in # Second argument
        g) #global| # Syntax to compare bash string to literal
             s="$(npm list --depth=0 -g $1 | grep $1 | cut -d @ -f 2)";
        echo "$s";
        ;;
        l) #Latest
             npm view $1 version; # 'npm info $1 version' does the same thing
       ;;
       *) echo 'Invalid arguments';
       ;;
       esac;
    ;;
    *) echo 'Invalid arguments';
    ;;
    esac;
}
export -f npmv
```

Now all I have to do is type:

- **npmv** for the version of npm, for example, `NPM version is: 4.2.0`
- **npmv <package-name>** for the local version, for example, `0.8.08`
- **npmv <package-name> g** for global version, for example, `0.8.09`
- **npmv <package-name> l** for latest version, for example, `0.8.10`

Note *-d* on the *cut* command means delimit by, followed by @, and then f means field. The '2' means the second field since there will be one either side of the *@* symbol.

Answer (score 7):

This is a simple question and should have a simpler answer than what I see in previous answers.

To see the installed npm packages with their version, the command is `npm ls --depth=0`, which, by default, displays what is installed locally. To see the globally installed packages, add the `-global` argument: `npm ls --depth=0 -global`.

`--depth=0` returns a list of installed packages without their dependencies, which is what you're wanting to do most of the time.

`ls` is the name of the command, and `list` [is an alias](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls) for `ls`.

Answer (score 6):

If you'd like to check for a particular module installed globally, on Unix-like systems use:

```
npm list -g --depth=0 | grep <module_name>
```

Answer (score 5):

To get *only* the installed version number, try:

```
npm list --depth=0 packagename | grep packagename | cut -d'@' -f2
```

E.g., the installed version number of PM2:

```
npm list --depth=0 pm2 | grep pm2 | cut -d'@' -f2
```

And to list globally installed packages, add the `-g` flag to the `npm list` command, eg:

```
npm list -g --depth=0 packagename | grep packagename | cut -d'@' -f2
```

Comment: For me `-f3` instead of `-f2`, but otherwise works great!

Answer (score 4):

I am using

```
npm list --depth=0 | grep module_name@
```

It brings me results like this:

```
module_name@2.1033.0
```

Answer (score 3):

### Access the *package.json* file

You can access the *package.json* or *bower.json* file of the package with:

#### Windows (with `notepad` installed):

```bash
notepad ./node_modules/vue-template-compiler/package.json`
```

This will open the `package.json` in Notepad which has the *version number* of the *packageName* you included in the command.

#### Mac/Linux:

```
cat node_modules/prettier/package.json | grep version
```

This will output something like this:

[image: screenshot of command output]

Comment: Not only are there much easier ways to do this, the version you have specified in your package.json may not actually be the installed version due to semver range notations.  That is, a dependency may be specified as version ^1.3.0, but that can mean anything from version 1.3.0 to 1.99.99

Comment: On [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows) only, presumably? What version / edition was this tried on? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40653641/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: Hi @PeterMortensen, I've update the answer with few more details.  Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 3):

We can  use

> npm info (your module name) version

Comment: This shows the latest version available, not the version in the local directory.

Comment: @christianbundy you can use  npm list --depth=0 | grep uuid

Comment: I had to use `npm list --depth=0 | grep uuid | awk '{ print $2; }' | cut -d '@' -f 2`, but yeah, this works as long as it's a top-level dependency. I don't think that's always the case though, based on the original question.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a space after "promise"?

Answer (score 2):

You can use *npm view [module] version*, *npm info [module] version*, *npm show [module] version* or *npm v [module] version* to check the version on an installed npm module.

Let's suppose my [Grunt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grunt_(software)) module version is the 0.4.5:

```
npm view grunt version => 0.4.5
npm info grunt version => 0.4.5
npm show grunt version => 0.4.5
npm v grunt version    => 0.4.5
```

Comment: All of those show the newest available version, not the currently installed version

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:
`npm show {package} version` shows the latest package version.
And if your package is outdated, `npm outdated` will show it with version info.

Comment: The OP was asking about the version of the *currently installed* package, not the latest version available in the package registry.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command to list the installed packages and their versions:

For a specific project (locally):

```bash
npm list
```

For a global package (globally installed):

```
npm list -g
```

If you want to find the version of a specific package, you can specify its name:

For a specific project (locally):

```bash
npm list <package-name>
```

For a global package (globally installed):

```bash
npm list -g <package-name>
```

This will display a tree-like structure of all the installed packages and their versions in your project or globally. Look for the package you're interested in, and its version should be displayed next to its name.

Comment: please do not write duplicated answer, many people already proposed that solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can define this alias in your terminal:

```bash
alias phas='npm list | grep'
```

### Usage

```bash
phas lod  
├── lodash@4.17.21
```