# How to tell if npm is fully updated

Tags: npm

I'm on Mac OS. When I run `sudo npm update -g`, I get a whole ton of output dumped out. Nothing actually says anything like "no updates needed," or "updated X, Y, Z." How do I know if all of the packages I've installed are up to date?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a `npm -v` command that you can use to check the version against what's on the website.

If you want to see the versions of the packages themselves, that question is answered over here:

`npm list` for local packages or `npm list -g` for globally installed packages.
Then you can check those versions against what's on the registry.

[Find the version of an installed npm package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972176/find-the-version-of-an-installed-npm-package)

Comment: Edited my question to be clearer. It's the packages I've installed I'm curious about, not npm itself.