# Grunt dependencies conflicts in Bootstrap

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, npm

I've downloaded Bootstrap source files from the [official website](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download) and I'm getting dependency conflicts when installing the project using node's `npm`. I have `grunt 0.4.3` installed on my machine but some bootstrap dependencies require `0.4.0` and some `0.4.1`.

The `npm install -g grunt-cli` command executed without any problems. Here's the log that I'm getting after executing `npm install` command:

```
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package grunt does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-banner@0.2.1 wants grunt@~0.4.1
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-clean@0.5.0 wants grunt@~0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-concat@0.3.0 wants grunt@~0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-connect@0.6.0 wants grunt@~0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-copy@0.5.0 wants grunt@~0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-csslint@0.2.0 wants grunt@~0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-cssmin@0.7.0 wants grunt@~0.4.1
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-jade@0.9.1 wants grunt@~0.4.1
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-jshint@0.8.0 wants grunt@~0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-less@0.9.0 wants grunt@~0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-qunit@0.4.0 wants grunt@~0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-uglify@0.3.3 wants grunt@~0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-watch@0.5.3 wants grunt@~0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-csscomb@2.0.1 wants grunt@~0.4.2
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-exec@0.4.3 wants grunt@~0.4
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-html-validation@0.1.13 wants grunt@~0.4.1
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-jekyll@0.4.1 wants grunt@~0.4.1
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-jscs-checker@0.3.2 wants grunt@0.4.2
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-saucelabs@5.0.1 wants grunt@~0.4.1
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-sed@0.1.1 wants grunt@~0.4

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\\Desktop\bootstrap-3.1.1
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.5
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\\Desktop\bootstrap-3.1.1\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I'm following [these](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap#compiling-css-and-javascript) installation steps.

How do I install this project cleanly, without any errors?

Comment: Btw, gruntjs 0.4.3 was released only yesterday.

Comment: This problem existed due to grunt-jscs-checker, which I'm the author. It was incorrectly requiring grunt to be strictly 0.4.2. As of now, bootstrap is using a newer version of grunt-jscs-checker, which fixed this problem.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I ran into this problem this morning too. I ended up changing line 30 in  Bootstrap's package.json file: from "~0.4.2" to "0.4.2":

```
27  "devDependencies": {
...
30    "grunt" : "0.4.2"
```

This means that 0.4.3 no longer matches the dependency spec but it also means you won't install new versions of grunt later. It's enough to get things working but you should probably change it back eventually (maybe in your next bootstrap project leave it alone).

Answer (score 12):

I encountered the same problem.  Performing the following:

```
bower install bootstrap
cd bower_components/bootstrap
npm install
```

Resulted in:

```
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package grunt does not satisfy 
   its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
```

I resolved this by first uninstalling grunt from the bootstrap directory

```
npm uninstall grunt
```

Then I installed grunt 0.4.2

```
npm install grunt@0.4.2
```

This time, `npm install` worked just fine

```
npm install
```

Comment: This is solution worked for me except that I used "npm install grunt@0.4.5"

Answer (score 5):

this problem is peerDependencies for grunt 
If you want to know this issue, then go to this url
http://blog.nodejs.org/2013/02/07/peer-dependencies/  

this is solution to solve it's problem 
step1 : You open the package.json in root directory
step2 : find the string  "grunt" : "~0.4.2"
step3 : Modify to "grunt": "0.4.2"
step4 : $  npm install

Answer (score 0):

You may have `Grunt 0.4.3` installed globally but nothing installed locally.

1. Run `$ grunt --version` to find which version you are on (not a necessary step).
2. Create a `package.json` file in the root of the folder you mean to have your project on.

   ```
   {
       "name" : "MyProject",
       "version" : "0.1.0",
       "author" : "My name",
       "private" : true,

       "devDependencies" : {
           "grunt" : "~0.4.2"
       }
   }
   ```
3. Run `$ npm install` while at the project's root folder.

Done!

--- UPDATE ---

You could use [Bower](http://bower.io/) to install Bootstrap for you. It makes cumbersome installations a breeze. Bootstrap's [*Getting Started*](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) guide advises using it!

```
$ bower install bootstrap
```

Here is a blog post that might be relevant to you: [Using Grunt + Bower with Laravel and Bootstrap](http://blog.elenakolevska.com/using-grunt-with-laravel-and-bootstrap/)

Or you could always opt to let `Grunt` manage the installation of `Bootstrap` and maintain it as a dependency... There are several plugins out there that do the heavy-lifting.

- https://www.google.com/search?q=github+grunt+bootstrap
- https://www.npmjs.org/search?q=bootstrap
- http://gruntjs.com/plugins + search for "bootstrap"

Comment: 1. This outputs `grunt-cli v0.1.13` 2 - 3. This also works .  It still doesn't help to install the Bootstrap project. I also tried installing `grunt@0.4.1` globally and then changing Bootstrap's grunt dependency to version `0.4.1` instead of `~0.4.2`, but the log is still the same.

Comment: @cNduo forget your Bootstrap project for a moment, let's debug `Grunt`. On Terminal, `cd` your way to an empty folder of your choice, even better if it's under your user. While there, create a `package.json` file and paste what I've posted on my answer. Once you've done that, run `$ npm install` on the same folder. `Grunt` should be then installed as a dependency to that folder. `~0.4.2` means "install latest version available, but minimum required version is 0.4.2".

Comment: Thanks for quick response. All of the above steps work fine, but what it have to do with the dependencies issues in Bootstrap?

Comment: But that's good, then we know the problem *is* with Bootstrap. I've had problems with 3rd party libraries that required newer / older version of `node` to run properly. When you run `$ node -v`, what do you get?

Comment: [My reply](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972176/find-the-version-of-an-installed-npm-package/18226166#18226166) to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972176/find-the-version-of-an-installed-npm-package/) might shed some light into what I meant in my last comment.

Comment: At the moment of posting the question it was `v0.10.15`, now I have `v0.10.26`, but still no success.

Comment: `v0.10.26` is the latest. You might want to try the version before the last, using [**nvm**](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). Once I had a big headache making [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) work, changing to the `node` version before the latest solved the issue. You might need to keep trying with different versions... What about trying to install previous versions of Bootstrap? Latest versions can be a bit too bleeding-edge sometimes.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but I ended up going with grunt@0.4.2, which blended smoothly into the project.

Comment: Never mind about that, I should have seen that coming. But now you know: better not to fiddle with too fresh latest versions of anything, they're too bleeding edge. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too.

I installed bootstrap using `git clone https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git` and it worked fine from that resulting bootstrap directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try `npm cache clean` and then try install command again.