# Unit tests error out with "Fatal error: write after end"

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, karma-runner, browserify, karma-jasmine

I'm running unit tests written in Jasmine in a PhantomJS browser using grunt-karma. The code I'm testing uses browserify.

When I run `grunt karma`, it loads up my modules and then errors out with `Fatal error: write after end`. Terminal output provided below:

```
Camerons-MacBook-Pro:Bookmarklet cameronnokes$ grunt karma
Running "karma:unit" (karma) task
DEBUG [config]: autoWatch set to false, because of singleRun
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading karma-* from /Users/cameronnokes/Repositories/Bookmarklet/node_modules
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin /Users/cameronnokes/Repositories/Bookmarklet/node_modules/karma-browserify.
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin /Users/cameronnokes/Repositories/Bookmarklet/node_modules/karma-jasmine.
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin /Users/cameronnokes/Repositories/Bookmarklet/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher.
DEBUG [preprocessor.browserify (framework)]: Writing to temp file: "22844b46ae091ac715aedfae5d2497cb".
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.16 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
DEBUG [temp-dir]: Creating temp dir at /var/folders/vs/zn48bjc56pj8b606y4db_k5m0000gn/T/karma-98875158
DEBUG [launcher]: /usr/local/bin/phantomjs /var/folders/vs/zn48bjc56pj8b606y4db_k5m0000gn/T/karma-98875158/capture.js
DEBUG [preprocessor.browserify]: Processing "/Users/cameronnokes/Repositories/Bookmarklet/test/test/content.test.js".
DEBUG [preprocessor.browserify]: Processing "/Users/cameronnokes/Repositories/Bookmarklet/test/test/messaging.test.js".
DEBUG [preprocessor.browserify]: Processing "/Users/cameronnokes/Repositories/Bookmarklet/test/test/store.test.js".
DEBUG [preprocessor.browserify]: Processing "/Users/cameronnokes/Repositories/Bookmarklet/test/test/tracking.test.js".
Fatal error: write after end
```

Googling this error doesn't bring up anything. Does anyone have any ideas on what's going on here? (Let me know if you need me to provide more information).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the same error when require is called second time while browserify parse the spec-files.

As suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972176/find-the-version-of-an-installed-npm-package) try to upgrade your browserify installation:

```
npm install --save-dev browserify@^4.0.0
```

To show the installed browserify version:

```
$ npm list browserify
app/
├── browserify@4.2.3
├─┬ gulp-browserify@0.4.6
│ └── browserify@3.46.1
└─┬ watchify@1.0.6
  └── browserify@5.13.1
```

Comment: I just ran npm update on my entire project and everything seems to work now. I'm on browserify ^4.2.3. Thanks!