# How to check version of cordova on Ubuntu?

Tags: node.js, cordova, ubuntu, npm, version

After installing [Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/) using `sudo npm install -g cordova` is there a way to verify whether it is downloaded, e.g. by checking the version number?

I have tried the following commands

- `cordova -v`
- `cordova platform version android`
- `dpkg -l cordova`
- `dpkg -s cordova | grep 'Version'`
- `apt-show-versions cordova`
- `apt-cache policy cordova`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, the package is [node package](http://nodejs.org/) managed by **[npm](https://www.npmjs.com/)**, the syntax to check a [node package version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10972176/2404470) will be used:

`npm -v cordova`

[image: checking node package cordova version]