# Why is npm not installing some folders?

Tags: npm

I forked primeng's repository and made one small modification.
When I npm install my repo it's giving me this error:

```
primeng@1.0.0-beta.10-SNAPSHOT  (git://github.com/matthieu- D/primeng.git#cec36bf71efe96b8a25d5d03f0c7d4ca6762443d)
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.0-beta.10
```

After installation, I have some files but others (components for example) are missing.

I have this package.json in my local project:

```
"@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
"@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.2",
"primeng": "git://github.com/matthieu-D/primeng.git",
"primeui": "^4.1.12",
"rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.6",
"zone.js": "^0.6.12"
```

I suspect the problem would be local and not from the fork.
PS: I forked another project ng2-translate and the src folder doesn't get installed: https://github.com/matthieu-D/ng2-translate 
I'm doing a :

```
npm install git://github.com/matthieu-D/ng2-translate.git
```

If I install the non-forked through through npm primeng, I get the errors but everything is cloned perfectly.
However if I install the non-forked through npm install github ... some folders don't install. 
It's either I'm using the wrong command or the repo somehow don't support installation through github.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would need to update your package "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.6" like

```
npm update --save rxjs@5.0.0-beta.10
```

I'm not pretty sure as I'm now get used to npm, but that's what the error say to me.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Tried your command, nothing changed.
Then I did npm install of .10.
 UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.0-beta.10

    npm WARN @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.4 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 but none was installed.
    npm WARN @angular/http@2.0.0-rc.4 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 but none was installed.
    npm WARN @angular/router@3.0.0-beta.2 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 but none was installed.

Comment: Try by uninstalling .6 and installing .10 with `npm uninstall --save rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6` and then `npm uninstall --save rxjs@5.0.0-beta.10`

Comment: Also, try by looking which exactly packages do you have, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10986132/1536999

Comment: Hm I have no hint what is going on here. I forked the project https://github.com/matthieu-D/primeng, I npm install in a clean space with nothing, no dep. I get no errors but whatever I do, npm only installs 3 files when there are a lot more to install. By the way the fork can be cleanly installed doing : npm install primeng-fork.

Comment: Just created a repo from scratch. Added components, gitignore. Everything is good. Added npmignore, components disappeared. Erased:  *.ts !*.d.ts from npmignore component is back.