# How to make sure npm install uses data from npm-shrinkwrap.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-shrinkwrap

In my javascript project I want to freeze the dependencies. For this I'm using npm-shrinkwrap https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap

I do the things that are written in the doc, and it works, but I can't find any evidence that the installation really uses data from file npm-shrinkwrap.json

Here is a more detailed explanation.

I have a super simple js project:

```
bessarabov@air:~/shrinkwrap$ ls
package.json
bessarabov@air:~/shrinkwrap$ cat package.json
{
    "dependencies" : {
        "express" : "4.14.0",
        "moment" : "2.14.1"
    }
}
```

Then I run `npm install` (here is the log — https://gist.github.com/bessarabov/9920d6dcb1cd71e504c6fe561e39643f ) And then I run:

```
bessarabov@air:~/shrinkwrap$ npm shrinkwrap
wrote npm-shrinkwrap.json
```

So, after I run this 2 commands I get new directory `node_modules` and a new file `npm-shrinkwrap.json`.

```
bessarabov@air:~/shrinkwrap$ ls
node_modules        npm-shrinkwrap.json package.json
```

Then I delete the installed libs: `rm -rf node_modules/` and run `npm install` again. And the log is exaclty the same that was without `npm-shrinkwrap.json` ( https://gist.github.com/bessarabov/33c9421744582501482e4f00453f9d38 )

So, I'm not sure the second `npm install` really uses data from `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file. I want to find a way to see in the log that `npm-shrinkwrap.json` was used.

I'm using:

```
bessarabov@air:~/shrinkwrap$ npm --version
3.3.12
bessarabov@air:~/shrinkwrap$ node --version
v5.3.0
```

But I've also tried node 6.5.0 and the result is the same.

Comment: [`npm la`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls)?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [Find the version of an installed npm package](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10972176/1048572) or are you looking for something else?

Comment: `npm la` and `npm list` shows the currently installed packages and there versions. I want to make sure that in several years when I run `npm install` I'll get the exact same list of packages and there versions.

Comment: You cannot test what a future `npm` is going to do in several years without a time machine.

Comment: I don't think you can do any better than to trust [npm's documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install): "*If the package has a shrinkwrap file, the installation of dependencies will be driven by that.*". If you want to see that in your logs, you might need to file a feature request with npm.

Comment: It makes sense. But I was hoping that there is some hidden flag that can be used to see that `npm-shrinkwrap.json` was used. Or maybe I'm using shrinkwrap incorrectly and because of this I don't see that it is used.