# Where are my globally installed packages?

Tags: node.js, powershell, npm

I've installed TypeScript using the command below.

> npm install -g typescript

The editor mentioned that it was too old so I used [this guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript#_using-newer-typescript-versions) to get the newest like this.

> npm install -g typescript@next

No error messages, all seems great. But I wanted to verify what version I've got so I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24501909/1525840) and executed the following.

> npm list typescript

It said *empty* and also gave me an error. Then I tried to show all packages like this.

> npm list

No error but nothing's listed. In still says *empty*. I executed the commands from PowerShell and I was both in a root directory and then also in the project's directory.

What am I missing? Probably something very stupid and basic.

Comment: Depends on the OS. I would suggest you start by `which npm` or `which node`

Comment: Check if you have other versions installed. Do you have a symbolic link that might be pointing to an older version?

Comment: @Dandy I might have. How do I check it? I ran *npm install typescript@next* to get the latest version **but** I believe there was something about an outdated version in the IDE. Not sure at the moment and I'm kind of scared of this whole thing. Sorry... How do I check the symbolic links and older version, please?

Comment: In my recent experience with npm, I downloaded an older version that pointed to a `nodejs` folder and not a `node` folder or the other way round I can't remember. So I had to link it via a symbolic link in order to an issue I was having. This actually caused more problems then it solved. Did you do this? Either way, my suggestion would be purging/uninstalling npm if you're just starting out and following this to ensure you have the latest stable release of npm: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-node

Comment: @CowAbunga If you want to install the latest version of the package you should use `@latest`, for example `npm i -g typescript@latest`

Comment: @Dandy The most surefire way I've found to install the latest version of NPM is by using **cURL**, `curl -L "https://npmjs.com/install.sh" | sudo sh`, if you're running on windows you'll need Cygwin or another shell like Git Bash, also on windows you can leave out the sudo

Comment: @peteb This is also a very good suggestion ^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With NPM, whenever you want to determine if something is installed locally or globally you need to specify that, just like you do when you're installing a package. By default, if you don't specify the global flag `-g` then npm will look within the current working directory.

`npm list -g typescript`

Comment: Just tested again with *npm list -g typescript* but got the same result... What else can be wrong?

Comment: I just ran the above command after doing `npm i -g typescript` and it was listed, perhaps try adding a depth option of 0, `npm ls -g --depth=0`. I'm running on Windows 7.

Comment: What is the "i" doing there?

Comment: `npm i` is an alias for `npm install`

Comment: But doesn't it **install** the package (if it's not installed already) and **first then** it lists it? It's so confusing...

Comment: Even if the package has already been installed, it is installed. What I said in my previous comment was, I installed `typescript` globally using `npm i -g typescript`, then I listed all my globally installed packages using `npm ls -g` and typescript was listed as globally installed. Have you tried using CMD or Git Bash to interact with NPM instead of Powershell?

Comment: @I haven't got that far. Very noob. Most scared. So confused.   :)      I see what you've done now - thanks. I'll stick with depth at the moment (I've seen other suggestions on that too). Well, if it would be easy, it wouldn't be exciting, right?

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the following for a locally installed package in Tester01 directory.

> PS C:\Users\_\GitHub\Tester01> npm list
>   C:\Users\_\GitHub\Tester01
>   └── typescript@2.0.3
>
> PS C:\Users\_\GitHub\Tester01> npm list -g
>   C:\Users\_\AppData\Roaming\npm
>   └── typescript@2.1.0-dev.20161010

When I exit the directory where TypeScript is locally installed I get this.

> PS C:\Users\_\GitHub\Tester01> cd..
>   PS C:\Users\_\GitHub> npm list
>   C:\Users\_\GitHub
>   └── (empty)
>
> PS C:\Users\_\GitHub> npm list -g
>   C:\Users\_\AppData\Roaming\npm
>   └── typescript@2.1.0-dev.20161010

If you only want to list the package that interests you (can't see the sane reason for that so I might be misunderstanding the question but still...) this is the syntax.

> PS C:\Users\_\GitHub\Tester01> npm list -g typescript@2.1.0-dev.20161010
>   C:\Users_\AppData\Roaming\npm
>   └── typescript@2.1.0-dev.20161010

However, I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10986132/1525840) but on my system (Win 10) it seems not to work. I've updated NPM to the latest version too (ver 3.10.8) to make sure but still get the error. I guess if you want to list them, you might use one of the following (although I don't like the syntax getting lengthy and I'm not certain on the details of what those are doing on a fundamental level).

> PS C:\Users\_\GitHub\Tester01> npm list typescript --depth=0
>   C:\Users_\GitHub\Tester01
>   └── typescript@2.0.3
>
> PS C:\Users\_\GitHub\Tester01> npm list install typescript
>   C:\Users\_\GitHub\Tester01
>   └── typescript@2.0.3

Comment: The latest version of NPM is v3.10.9 not v2.15.9, also the differences between v2 and v3 of NPM are quite dramatic.

Comment: @peteb Hehe, I got the latest version of **Node** and forgot to update NPM. My bad - it's 6 AM at my place. I should be sleeping, not horsing around on the internet... Thanks for the correction, mate.