# How can I save all the installed node modules in package.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules, package.json

How can I save all the installed node modules in package.json without reinstalling them?

I have something like `npm init --yes` but, I'm not kinda sure if that works.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972176/find-the-version-of-an-installed-npm-package

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no way to get that stuff with some inbuilt modules

But you can write your own code to get that info and update in in your own `package.json` file

```
var fs = require("fs");

function getPackageInfo() {
  fs.readdir("./node_modules", function(err, module) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
    console.log(module)
    module.forEach(function(dir) {
      if (dir.indexOf(".") !== 0) {
        var packageFile = "./node_modules/" + dir + "/package.json";
        if (fs.existsSync(packageFile)) {
          fs.readFile(packageFile, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
            } else {
              var json = JSON.parse(data);
              console.log('"' + json.name + '": "' + json.version + '",');
            }
          });
        }
      }
    });

  });
}

getPackageInfo();
```

**Output**

```
"setprototypeof": "1.0.1",
"raw-body": "2.1.7",
"source-map": "0.4.4",
"statuses": "1.3.0",
"transformers": "2.1.0",
"type-is": "1.6.13",
"methods": "1.1.2",
"uglify-js": "2.7.3",
"uglify-to-browserify": "1.0.2",
"utils-merge": "1.0.0",
"unpipe": "1.0.0",
"vary": "1.0.1",
"void-elements": "2.0.1",
"with": "4.0.3",
"window-size": "0.1.0",
"wordwrap": "0.0.3",
"yargs": "3.10.0",
"mime-db": "1.24.0",
...................
..................
..................
.................
```

You can also use

`npm list --depth=0`

command to get packages list and version by `child_process spawn`

Comment: This solution is good as a workaround as there no direct method available. But this might be problematic as npm now (newer versions >= v3) creates flat tree and as a result this code would generate a larger dependency tree then actual.

Comment: u can also use `npm list --depth=0` command to get packages list and version  using *shelljs* or *child_process spawn* instead of folder and file traversing

Comment: Do agree, still we need to do some stuff to get it done. But your point is correct I am updating my answer

Comment: But what I want to do is write all the node modules via npm command line that are not written in package.json... This solution doesn't answer my question, but thank you.