# How to determine the version of the node module from the files in the modules folder?

Tags: node.js, angular

I can specify the version of the node module to be installed in my angular application's **package.json** file, but is there a way of confirming that the specified version has been downloaded to the application's node_modules folder after **npm install**?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972176/find-the-version-of-an-installed-npm-package) question covers a similar topic, however I am looking for a confirmation of the version in the folder structure of the module itself.

Comment: `npm list --depth 0` will show you what's installed, or just look in that module's own `package.json` for its version. But why is this something you're so worried about?

Comment: Thank you @jonrsharpe. We had a conflicting opinion with the vendor and needed an explicit proof of the installed package.

Comment: you can also look at "version" field of "package.json" file of the node module you are interested. it should be in "node_modules" folder of your project

Answer (score 0):

You can look at your `package-lock.json` file to see every package (and sub package) version that has been installed.

Comment: Thanks, I do not see the file with that name in the application folder.

Comment: What version of `npm` are you using? This was added in npm v5+

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json

Comment: Mine is 3.10.10. Will upgrade and check this out. Thank you.