# How do I check react-360 code has been updated on npm

Tags: reactjs

Back in September, I had been working on a reactvr/react-360 project in which I needed to manipulate the `scaleZ` property of an object. I discovered that it didn't work. When I posted the issue I was told that the fix was in the latest code but not in the npm module yet.

I tried creating a new project now and still have the same issues with scaleZ. How do I know if I have the latest code with npm? Where do I find this npm module? I'm new to node and npm.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972176/find-the-version-of-an-installed-npm-package

Comment: Thanks, this definitely helps