# NPM React-router Version Too advanced?

Tags: javascript, npm, react-router

I can run `npm -v react-router` on my react app and I get v6.9.0. But if I look at the [npmjs page for react-router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router) the newest version is 5.0.1. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

That's your version of npm. If you type `npm -v` and then `npm -v <any arg>`, you'll get the same answer.

Comment: Derp. Should've gone with `npm list react-router`

Answer (score 1):

`npm -v` returns the npm version (6.9.0)

To get installed react-router version:

`npm list react-router`.

More info about npm list command: [Find the version of an installed npm package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972176/find-the-version-of-an-installed-npm-package)