# is there a way to check what versions of a library had been installed?

Tags: npm, version, rollback

When installing npm libraries, If I overwrite one of them by using `@latest`, or simply `@1.2.0`, `@5.4.3`...is there a way to know what versions had been installed prior to installing the newer versions?

I have encountered a problem in a latest version of a library, and I've been trying to check many versions to see if it would work, but none of them do.

I'm trying to figure out what version number I had before all my tries.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the version of an installed npm package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972176/find-the-version-of-an-installed-npm-package)

Comment: It seems it just returns the installed version.

Comment: What I would need is something like a control of versions installed from the very beginning of installations.

Comment: Well, you did say, _"is there a way to know what versions have been installed?"_ however I missed the part in question that read _"I'm trying to figure out what version number I had before all my tries"_. The short answer is _"No"_ npm has no built feature. If retrospectively you had run something like `npm list --json > ./path/to/before.json` before installing new version(s). Then after installing new version(s) of package(s) you could have run `npm list --json > ./path/to/after.json`. Then diff the two file (before.json, and after.json) to check what changed.

Comment: I suggest you consider using of a [npm lockfile](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-locks) (`package-lock.json` / `npm-shrinkwrap.json`) in the future to negate this kind of scenario from happening again. If you had committed a lockfile to your VCS (e.g. git) it will provide a means to; _diff_ changes (before and after install updates), and restore the exact same node_modules tree when problems occur.