# How to know the version of currently installed package from yarn.lock

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, yarnpkg

I am writing an internal tool which compares the version installed in a project and only allow certain version to be passed. For that I have to check the version which is resolved in the `yarn.lock` file, as package.json file has a semver range, not specific version and it doesn't tell you the dependency of the dependency anyway.

I tried using `yarn list` command, but it prints the semver range too and is very hard to parse (even with `--json` option).
So `yarn.lock` seems like the only way. I know that `yarn.lock` may have separate versions of the same package and in that case I want only the version which is installed in. the `node_nodules` (must be just one of them). I have no idea how to parse the lockfile though.

Another way I could think of is actually going into `node_modules` folder and checking the version in the `package.json` of the package.

None of the above option looks clean to me. Is there any way I can know the resolved version of a specific package (provided I know the name of the package and I know that it's installed) easily and as cleanly as possible?

**Update**:
I actually wanted all the versions of the installed package (even if they're really deep in the dependency tree).

Comment: Not quite sure If it helps but since you know the name of the package. `npm info [package_name] version` can be helpful to retrieve the package version.

Comment: @VaritJPatel It doesn't return the installed package version. It just fetches the information from the npm registry

Comment: Probably the best way is to use `require.resolve` to look up the location of the node module that will actually be included, and then read the `package.json`.  https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_resolve_request_options

Comment: It's a bit ridiculous that this isn't possible/easy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the version of an installed npm package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972176/find-the-version-of-an-installed-npm-package)

Comment: @SeetaRamYadav This question is already answered a couple of years ago. Furthermore, I asked about yarn command, not npm. Also there's no correct answer which fixed my issue other than my own answer for this question.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I found out that `yarn why`is the best way to find out the currently installed version of a package (Thanks to one of my colleague who point out to me). This is how my test code looks in the JavaScript.

```
const { spawnSync } = require('child_process');
const packageName = 'micromatch';
const whyBuffer = spawnSync('yarn', ['why', packageName]);
const grepBuffer = spawnSync('grep', ['Found'], { input: whyBuffer.stdout });
const outputArray = grepBuffer.stdout.toString().split('\n');
console.log(outputArray); // ['info \r=> Found "micromatch@3.1.10"',    'info \r=> Found "fast-glob#micromatch@4.0.2"', ''  ]
const parsedOutputArray = outputArray.filter(output => output.length > 0).map((output) => output.split('@')[1].replace('"', ''))
console.log(parsedOutputArray); // [ '3.1.10', '4.0.2' ]
```

Comment: The answer works for me but could be improved by handling scoped packages cases (when package name starts with `@`): 
```output.split('@')[1]``` here use the last element of array but not the second.

Comment: you want the fastest, why not `cat package.json | jq -r '.dependencies.pckname'`

Comment: @TimeKiller It doesn't tell you the exact version of installed package. Also it doesn't tell you anything about transitive dependencies.

Answer (score 74):

Since, you know the name of the package, do this:

```
yarn list --pattern <package_name>
```

The above command will get you all installed versions of a package at any depth. For example, I have different versions of `camelcase` library installed at various depths. On running the command : `yarn list --pattern "camelcase"`, this is the output:

```
yarn list v1.22.5
├─ camelcase@6.2.0
└─ yargs-parser@13.1.2
   └─ camelcase@5.3.1
```

Comment: I guess the pattern value needs to be a regex string. I checked with `react` and it listed all the packages having react in their name.

Comment: Couldn't find a script named "list"

Comment: Both `list` and `why` return me non-installed versions if they are inside the range defined in the `package.json`, they do not return the actually installed versions found in the lock file.

Answer (score 7):

For programmatic use, I like `yarn list`:

```
yarn list --pattern lodash --depth=0 --json --non-interactive --no-progress | jq -r '.data.trees[].name'
lodash@4.17.21
lodash.defaults@4.2.0
lodash.flatten@4.4.0
lodash.isarguments@3.1.0
lodash.memoize@3.0.4
```

For even better programmatic use: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@yarnpkg/lockfile

Comment: There's already an answer with the same solution. How's that any better? Additionally, if I wanted to know about just the lodash package, I'll have to add another filter for it.

Comment: @noob this also adds some useful options

Answer (score 4):

Since `yarn list` isn't yet implemented for newer versions of Yarn, and `yarn why` can be a bit hard to parse, `yarn info` is another option. It outputs the version resolved in yarn.lock.

```sh
$ yarn info sass -A
└─ sass@npm:1.41.0
   ├─ Version: 1.41.0
   │
   ├─ Exported Binaries
   │  └─ sass
   │
   └─ Dependencies
      └─ chokidar@npm:>=3.0.0 <4.0.0 → npm:3.5.2
```

Or, to just get the name and version:

```sh
$ yarn info sass -A --name-only
└─ sass@npm:1.41.0
```

And to get just the version, you can use the `--json` flag to output in a more machine readable format, and then parse it with `jq`:

```sh
$ yarn info sass -A --json | jq ".children.Version"
"1.41.0"
```

Comment: what '-A' is for?

Comment: The -A flag stands for —all: “Print versions of a package from the whole project.” I believe this would help if you had a monorepo and just wanted to run yarn info from the root directory.

Comment: Ever since `yarn` developers seem to have moved around pretty much every invocation in the CLI, most of the answers on the Internet on how to do something with `yarn` don't work any longer. Yours with `yarn info` was a welcoming change for someone that was just exposed to `yarn` in 2022 ;).

Comment: Thanks, I agree! I remember this being frustrating when I was trying to find the answer to this question myself :)

Answer (score 3):

You can check with

via yarn `yarn list --depth=0`
or via npm 'npm list --depth=0`

Comment: btw it seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972176/find-the-version-of-an-installed-npm-package?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

`npm list --depth=0` is 1000x faster than `yarn why <each package>`.
It also tells you about extraneous dependencies, unmet peer deps, etc, but the output is very clean - still cleaner than `yarn why`

Comment: How can you be so sure that it's 1000x faster? Is there any benchmark? Moreover, I am not interested in depth 0 deps only. Moreover, I don't want to know about every package. I just wanna know if a given package is installed or not, if it is, what's the installed version. Parsing the entire list seems slower than just using `yarn why`.

Comment: One additional point is that I am using yarn as the package manager, not npm. When using `npm list` without `package-lock.json` I received a lot of errors for missing deps.

Answer (score 0):

Update to Noah Allen answer, for yarn 1.22.19, children is data and Version is lowercase.

Run this command in your terminal to see the currently installed version.

```
yarn info sass -A --json | jq ".data.version"
```

Comment: I think `version` is just the latest stable version?