# Command to display the current version of package using npm or yarn?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

Is there npm or yarn command to show which version of dependency is installed in my project?

`yarn info` show my the version that exist in the npm registry. for example I set `jest` to be: `"jest": "27.5.1"` but when I run `yarn info jest version` it show me `28.1.0`

I know I can open the lock file, but is hard to handle that.

Comment: For npm `cd` to your project directory then use the [npm ls](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-ls) command, e.g. `npm ls <package_name>`. Note you can also include the [--depth](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-ls#depth) option to list only the top level instance of the dependency, e.g. `npm ls <package_name> --depth 0`. For modern Yarn use the [why](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/why) command and for older versions of yarn use the [yarn list](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/list/) command, e.g.  `yarn list --pattern <package_name> --depth=0`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the version of an installed npm package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972176/find-the-version-of-an-installed-npm-package)

Comment: ... and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60454251/how-to-know-the-version-of-currently-installed-package-from-yarn-lock) for yarn?

Answer (score 2):

In node package manager simply use :

```
 npm view <package_name> version
```

current installed version :

```
 npm list <package_name>
```

Yarn :

```
yarn info <package_name> version
```

Comment: no. those commands are show my the version that exist in the npm registry. for example I set `jest` to be: `"jest": "27.5.1"` but when I run `yarn info jest version` it show me `28.1.0`

Comment: use npm list <package_name> to see current version