# How to get current version of some node.js package?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, yarnpkg

How to get current version (that will be installed according to package-lock.json or yarn.lock) of some package from package-lock.json and yarn.lock?

Is any **API** (not a command line tool) to be more independent from format in future?

For example I whould like to do with `node` same as this `perl` code snippet:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
 
use version;
 
my @versions = ( 'v5.11', '5.011', '5.012', '5.1.1', '5.1.2', '5.10',  '5.10_01');
 
 
my @sorted = sort { version->parse( $a ) <=> version->parse( $b ) } @versions;
for my $s (@sorted) {
    say $s;
}
```

Comment: When you say current, do you mean installed version or latest?

Comment: I add notice - actually to check before installed (same as `yarn outdated` ses)

Comment: `npm v <package name> version`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the version of an installed npm package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972176/find-the-version-of-an-installed-npm-package)

Comment: you could also use `npm outdated --json` if you want to do it programmatically.

Comment: I am asking API not a command line tool - suggested already answered question is not match requirement.

Comment: npm is not built into node, so no there is no API use `child_process` to execute the cmd.

Comment: That is just operations with a strings - sure already exists and used in `yarn`/`npm` - do we need to spawn `sed` or `awk` to just operation with strings?

Comment: no as previously mentioned there is `--json` format which you can do JSON.parse on

Comment: Not a question how to parse json but how to parse and compare versions

Comment: also you can `require('./package.json')` or `require('./package-lock.json')` if you want an initial list before running anything.

Comment: Not a question how to parse json but how to parse and compare versions - josn format may be changed and version is more complicated format than just numbers and dots (for example `^7.0.0`)

Comment: versions will be in semvar, again nothing built in to compare versions but you could use a package https://www.npmjs.com/package/semver or if thats to heavy there is this https://github.com/substack/semver-compare/blob/master/index.js

Comment: Thanks @Lawrence Cherone - this is an answer

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone - you have to say `nothing built in to compare versions` - but there is an comparision `semver.gt('1.2.3', '9.8.7')`

Answer (score -1):

If cowsay is your package,

```
$ npm list cowsay
```