# how to know tar version in our NPM (create-react-app)?

Tags: npm, create-react-app, tar, npm-package

I write this command **NPM i tar**
now how I can found my tar version?

I want to know my tar version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use npm list for local packages or list -g for globally installed packages.
or you can pass the package name as the argument in npm list like this :
npm list tar.
[you can find more detail in this topic.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972176/find-the-version-of-an-installed-npm-package)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command:

```
 npm list tar
```

or

```
npm list tar | grep tar@
```

This will retrieve the tar version, something like this:

```
tar@4.4.10
```