# Error installing SailsJS in OpenShift

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, openshift, sails.js

```
info: Starting app...


Grunt :: module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '/var/lib/openshift/54a3a0ec4382ecf1130000f1/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/sails/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)

    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

Comment: `npm install -g grunt-cli` ?

Comment: @Plato Open shift doesn't allow me to npm. Its done by package.json

Answer (score 1):

OpenShift needs grunt separately added to package.json, it does not contain it out of box.

Try to add the following there to get grunt working:

```
   "dependencies": { "grunt-cli": ">=0.1.13", "grunt": "~0.4.4",
```

**Source:**
https://gist.github.com/mdunisch/4a56bdf972c2f708ccc6

Comment: Right way seems to be using the following commands to generate the line: `npm install <pkg> --save` or `npm install <pkg> --save-dev` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961502/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-build-the-package-json-file-for-node-js-projects

Comment: `npm init` is for adding the package.json for first time, the above ones editing it.