# How can I save newly-created node modules to my package.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-shrinkwrap

I make new features as node modules.

```
 mkdir node_modules/some-feature
 cd node_modules/some-feature
 npm init
```

Of course, when I shrinkwrap, I get error messages like:

```
npm ERR! extraneous: some-feature@0.0.0 /myprojectdir/node_modules/some-feature

npm ERR! extraneous: something-else@0.0.0 /myprojectdir/node_modules/something-elsear
```

Is there a quick way to save the newly created extraneous packages to `package.json`?

Comment: [Is there a way to automatically build the package.json file for Node.js projects](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9961502/1700321)

Comment: @AleksandrM I'm aware of `npm init`, I mentioned it in the question you're replying to. It does not do what I'm asking.

Comment: Yes, I know. Keep reading - http://stackoverflow.com/a/13381344/1700321 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/21123358/1700321.

Comment: Ah thanks @AleksandrM. The second link doesn't apply (install --save won't work for an original module that's already installed, it will just 404 and not modify package.json) but the script in the first link does. Feel free to add it as an answer.