# how to Add my node_module, modules into package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I have some module in my node_module folder but because I am amateur in `nodejs`, when I wanted to install theme, I forgot to use `--save` with `npm install`.now I have lots of module but my `package.json` is empty so is there any way to add theme into `package.json`.
Sorry if my question is silly one I am beginner in `nodejs`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Simply change into the directory containing `node_modules`, backup any existing `package.json` in there, then use `npm init` to re-create the `package.json`.

The generated `package.json` will include any modules that already exist within `node_modules`.

Sample run:

```
$ cd /my/project
$ mv package.json package.json.bak # Backup package.json
$ npm init                         # Recreate package.json with dependencies populated
```

Comment: "It only covers the most common items, and tries to guess sensible defaults." Hence, not all existing libraries in node_modules are added.

Answer (score 1):

**Already asked and well answered!**

Here're different ways suggested to create / maintain `package.json` file
[Is there a way to automatically build the package.json file for Node.js projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961502/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-build-the-package-json-file-for-node-js-projects)

Answer (score 0):

Its simple. Edit the package.json file and add the following for development dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.0.2",
    "broccoli-merge-trees": "^0.2.1",
    "broccoli-svg-sprite": "^1.0.3",
     ......
}
```

To get a list of package names and version numbers, you may look at node_modules/module folder/package.json for each of the modules to pick up the official package name and version. It will be of the form:

```
    {
  "name": "<<name of the package>>",
  "version": "2.1.0",
  "description": "broccoli asset revisions (fingerprint)",
....
}
```

just copy the name and version information from above into devDependencies into your project's package.json and you should be good to go.

Also have a look here [Is there a way to automatically build the package.json file for Node.js projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961502/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-build-the-package-json-file-for-node-js-projects)

and here: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json

Comment: Is the only way to add theme one by one I said I have lots module if I want to add theme one by it will take hours

Answer (score 0):

You can install the same package again using `npm install --save <package>` and it should just replace the current package files with freshly installed ones. It will also add the packages you already added with the default version notation.

Comment: I have already known this approach but I looking for way without installing my modules again