# How do I save all the dependencies I install through npm into my package.json file?

Tags: json, node.js, heroku, npm

I ran `npm install` for a lot of packages, but I forgot to include the `--save` argument. Now when I try to deploy on Heroku I get errors for missing certain dependencies. How can I automatically add those dependencies to my `package.json` file without doing `npm install --save` for each one?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add all installed packages not installed with `--save` to your `package.json` automatically by calling `npm init`. It will append the dependencies to your existing ones. No settings in your file should be lost. Still don't forget to make a backup of the file to be 100% secure!

If the dependencies have not been appended, it can happen that just the merging failed:

1. **Backup** your existing `package.json` in order to keep the dependencies you have in your `package.json` already and all the other settings. We need this file later again.
2. **Delete** the `package.json`  and **run** `npm init` in order to create a new `package.json` including the modules installed without `--save` in `dependencies`.
3. **Merge** the dependencies of your newly created `package.json` into your old one manually. Restore your merged `package.json`.

Comment: won't this replace my project files?

Comment: Your project files and node_modules are not touched by this. It's all about the package.json

Answer (score 1):

Someone already wrote a script for this.
Go to following link

[stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13381344/2277289)

here is complete code
run this code inside your project folder

```
  var fs = require("fs");

  function main() {
    fs.readdir("./node_modules", function (err, dirs) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
      }
      dirs.forEach(function(dir){
        if (dir.indexOf(".") !== 0) {
          var packageJsonFile = "./node_modules/" + dir + "/package.json";
          if (fs.existsSync(packageJsonFile)) {
            fs.readFile(packageJsonFile, function (err, data) {
              if (err) {
                console.log(err);
              }
              else {
                var json = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log('"'+json.name+'": "' + json.version + '",');
              }
            });
          }
        }
      });

    });
  }
  main();
```

It will print all the dependencies inside node_module folder as given below.

```
"ansi-regex": "2.0.0",
"ansi-styles": "2.2.1",
"asn1": "0.2.3",
"assert-plus": "0.2.0",
"asynckit": "0.4.0",
"aws-sign2": "0.6.0",
"bcrypt-pbkdf": "1.0.0",
"aws4": "1.4.1",
"bindings": "1.2.1",
"bl": "1.1.2",
"boom": "2.10.1",
"caseless": "0.11.0",
"chalk": "1.1.3",
"combined-stream": "1.0.5",
"core-util-is": "1.0.2",
"compress": "0.99.0",
"commander": "2.9.0",
"cryptiles": "2.0.5",
"delayed-stream": "1.0.0",
"dashdash": "1.14.0",
"debug": "0.7.4",
"ecc-jsbn": "0.1.1",
"ejs": "2.3.4",
"escape-string-regexp": "1.0.5",
```

copy and paste inside your package.json json as follow

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    //paste above printed data here
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```