# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function when mounting a volume from the local directory into a next.js container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, next.js

I'm trying to mount a volume from my local directory for Next.js/React's hot reload during development. My current docker-compose.development.yml looks like this:

```yaml
services:
  web:
    command: next dev
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
      - /usr/src/app/.next
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
```

It extends my main docker-compose with the command `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.development.yml up --build`:

```yaml
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: /bin/sh -c 'npm run build && npm start'
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
      - 5432:5432
    env_file:
      - .env.local
```

It works fine without the development overrides and without docker. I believe this problem has to do with running `next dev` in a container as the problem persists even after removing the volume bindings. Here is the [full call stack](https://pastebin.com/mAUuHqUF). It points to the error being in the `src/pages/_app.tsx`  file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had `NODE_ENV` set to `production` instead of `development` in my Dockerfile. I assume it was conflicting with one of the steps for hot reloading.

Answer (score 1):

This are the basic steps to troubleshoot an issue when you can build your project in one environment and you are not able to do it in another.

- Make sure the `npm install` was run before the build starts.

  I can not see from the shared snippets you have shared if this was done. To build in the container you need to have the dependancies installed.
- Make sure that your `package.json` is up to date with the versions of the packages/modules that are installed in the development environment.

  If you don't have the `package.json` or it was not maintained you can check in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961502/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-build-the-package-json-file-for-node-js-projects) how to generate it again.
- Next to check is the C/C++ build environment. some of the modules require C/C++ or C#/mongo to build environments to be present in the image. Also, most often there will be requirement for specific `dev` shared libraries to be installed.

  Check which dependancies are required for your packages and which libraries are required to be installed in the OS for the modules to work.
- Finally, some modules are OS dependent (ex. work only on Windows, or only on macOS), or architecture dependent (amd64, arm64, etc.)

  Ream the information about the package/module and research it on internet. If you have such modules, you will face challenges to package them in a container, so best approach here is to refactor them out from your project before you can containerize it.

Comment: Alright, I'll definitely look into the dependencies, thank you!